# Starting a new room planner web application

Tags: python, user-interface, web-applications

So I'm learning Python and beginning to grasp the fundamentals. I want to start a project that seems slightly over ambitious for my current knowledge level but I think I can do it bit by bit and it will look good in my portfolio.

Basically, I'd like to create a web application that generates a grid and allows the user to create rooms to scale. Dragging and dropping pieces of furniture to visualise how much space they will have between various pieces of furniture and checks if pieces will fit. Also I'd like the user to be able to save real furniture for example, using the Ikea website that will, when they're finished, generate a basket containing links and pictures to the items they have chosen and give them an idea of total cost.

It feels daunting starting out, what modules/libraries would I use to get this going? I'd like it to be a web app that is mobile friendly ideally?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Making interactive web apps like that are not really within Python's capability.

On the web, Python (via Django) is good for back-end things and making websites, but for client-side interactivity like you are suggesting, you need to use Javascript.

There is a tool called [Brython](https://brython.info/) that lets you write client-side Python and then it will convert it into Javascript for you, but it is quite complicated.

I would suggest picking another project for Python ([here](https://realpython.com/intermediate-python-project-ideas/) is a great list), or if you want to continue with that furniture idea, then picking up some JS, React, and using a library like [react-dnd](https://github.com/react-dnd/react-dnd) would be a good starting point.